# MsBuild publishing multiple folders at target and not using input parameters

Tags: yaml, azure-pipelines, publishing

I'm deploying a WPS application to multiple different shared network drives. Each application will have to target a different Database. On top of this since I'm using clickOnce deployment each location will need its own PublishUrl and InstallUrl.

I currently have a single pipeline that can deploy to each location (eventually I'll break it up into multiple pipelines).

The problems are that when it publishes it creates two folders. One `MyAppName` and another `MyAppNameapp.publish` it does not set `InstallUrl`, `PublishUrl`, `UpdateUrl` or `$(AssemblyVersion)` and (don't know if is an actual issue) sets the deploymentProvider codebase to a folder inside my local agent (used to run this pipe).

```
Folder:MyAppName
  Contains
    A published version of my application

Folder:MyAppNameapp.publish
  Contains
    Setup.exe
    MyAppName.application
      Inside File 
        <deploymentProvider codebase="[Folder inside my local agent]" />
        Missing InstallUrl, PublishUrl, UpdateUrl
    MyAppName.exe
    Folder:Application Files
      Contains
        Folder:MyAppNameapp_$(AssemblyVersion) 
          Contains
            A published version of my application
```

How to I limit MsBuild to only create `MyAppNameapp.publish` (but renamed to `MyAppName`)

This is MsBuild task being used to create these folders.

```
- task: MSBuild@1
  inputs:
      solution: 'Tenant Tool Analytics Module/*.csproj'
      msbuildArguments: '/target:Publish 
      /p:ApplicationVersion=$(AssemblyVersion) 
      /p:UpdateEnabled=true /p:UpdateMode=Foreground 
      /p:ProductName=TenantAnalyticsTool 
      /p:InstallUrl=c:\sandbox\deploytesting\siteA
      /p:PublishUrl=c:\sandbox\deploytesting\siteA
      /p:UpdateUrl=c:\sandbox\deploytesting\siteA
      /p:OutputPath=c:\sandbox\deploytesting\siteA
      /p:OutDir=c:\sandbox\deploytesting\siteA '
      msbuildArchitecture: x64
```

I've tried:

-redirecting OutputPath and OutDir to a different location but then nothing gets created at `c:\sandbox\deploytesting\siteA`.

-removing both causes no folder to be created. If I remove only one (either) MSBuild doesn't copy all the files over.

Complete yaml

```
# ASP.NET Core (.NET Framework)
# Build and test ASP.NET Core projects targeting the full .NET Framework.
# Add steps that publish symbols, save build artifacts, and more:
# https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/languages/dotnet-core

trigger:
- master

pool: Default

variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

steps:
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    restoreSolution: '$(solution)'

- task: MSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: 'Tenant Tool Analytics Module/*.csproj'
    msbuildArchitecture: 'x64'


- task: VisualStudioTestPlatformInstaller@1
  inputs:
    packageFeedSelector: 'nugetOrg'
    versionSelector: 'latestStable'


- task: VSTest@2
  inputs:
    testSelector: 'testAssemblies'
    testAssemblyVer2: |
      **\*test*.dll
      !**\*TestAdapter.dll
      !**\obj\**
    searchFolder: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
    vsTestVersion: 'toolsInstaller'

- task: MSBuild@1
  inputs:
      solution: 'Tenant Tool Analytics Module/*.csproj'
      msbuildArguments: '/target:Publish 
      /p:ApplicationVersion=$(AssemblyVersion) 
      /p:UpdateEnabled=true /p:UpdateMode=Foreground 
      /p:ProductName=TenantAnalyticsTool 
      /p:InstallUrl=c:\sandbox\deploytesting\siteA
      /p:PublishUrl=c:\sandbox\deploytesting\siteA
      /p:UpdateUrl=c:\sandbox\deploytesting\siteA
      /p:OutputPath=c:\sandbox\deploytesting\siteA
      /p:OutDir=c:\sandbox\deploytesting\siteA '
      msbuildArchitecture: x64
```

New MSBuild@1 test.

```
- task: MSBuild@1
  inputs:
      solution: 'Tenant Tool Analytics Module/*.csproj'
      msbuildArguments: '/t:Publish 
      /p:ApplicationVersion=$(Build.BuildId)
      /p:UpdateEnabled=true 
      /p:UpdateMode=Foreground 
      /p:ProductName=TenantAnalyticsTool 
      /p:OutputPath=c:\sandbox\deploytesting\siteC
      /p:InstallUrl=c:\sandbox\deploytesting\siteC
      /p:PublishUrl=c:\sandbox\deploytesting\siteC'
      msbuildArchitecture: x64
```

Outcome: Folder structure remains unchanged

[image]

Inside of MyAppName.application

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<asmv1:assembly xsi:schemaLocation="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1 assembly.adaptive.xsd" manifestVersion="1.0" xmlns:asmv1="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2" xmlns:asmv2="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2" xmlns:xrml="urn:mpeg:mpeg21:2003:01-REL-R-NS" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:asmv3="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3" xmlns:dsig="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" xmlns:co.v1="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:clickonce.v1" xmlns:co.v2="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:clickonce.v2">
  <assemblyIdentity name="MyAppName" version="1.0.0.34" publicKeyToken="0000000000000000" language="neutral" processorArchitecture="amd64" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" />
  <description asmv2:publisher="CBRE" asmv2:product="Tenant Tool Analytics Module" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" />
  <deployment install="true" co.v1:createDesktopShortcut="true">
    <subscription>
      <update>
        <beforeApplicationStartup />
      </update>
    </subscription>
    <deploymentProvider codebase="file://catd...[Not a location specified in the pipe].../MyAppName.application" />
  </deployment>
  <compatibleFrameworks xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:clickonce.v2">
    <framework targetVersion="4.7.2" profile="Full" supportedRuntime="4.0.30319" />
  </compatibleFrameworks>
  <dependency>
    <dependentAssembly dependencyType="install" codebase="Application Files\Tenant Tool Analytics Module_198\Tenant Tool Analytics Module.exe.manifest" size="8606">
      <assemblyIdentity name="Tenant Tool Analytics Module.exe" version="1.0.0.34" publicKeyToken="0000000000000000" language="neutral" processorArchitecture="amd64" type="win32" />
      <hash>
        <dsig:Transforms>
          <dsig:Transform Algorithm="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:HashTransforms.Identity" />
        </dsig:Transforms>
        <dsig:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha256" />
        <dsig:DigestValue>R5zudfS3VXtM5dKoEFbHYoZih0Sxr8CjX33H5FgvBk8=</dsig:DigestValue>
      </hash>
    </dependentAssembly>
  </dependency>
</asmv1:assembly>
```

Comment: Any update for this case?

Comment: Thanks for your help. I got pulled away from this for the moment so I came in a little early to test your solution. I'll update my question with the new BSBuild I used and its outcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

YAML that finally worked for me. Repeating the two MSBuild tasks I can publish the application to a network drive.

```
# ASP.NET Core (.NET Framework)
# Build and test ASP.NET Core projects targeting the full .NET Framework.
# Add steps that publish symbols, save build artifacts, and more:
# https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/languages/dotnet-core

trigger:
- master

pool: Default

variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'
  NewBuildID: $(BuildID)

steps:
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    restoreSolution: '$(solution)'


- task: MSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: 'Tenant Tool Analytics Module/*.csproj'      
    msbuildArguments: ' 
      /p:UpdateEnabled=true 
      /p:UpdateMode=Foreground 
      /p:ProductName="Tenant Analytics Tool"
      /p:BootstrapperEnabled=false
      '
    msbuildArchitecture: 'x64'

- task: MSBuild@1
  inputs:
      solution: 'Tenant Tool Analytics Module/*.csproj'
      msbuildArguments: '/t:Publish 
      /p:UpdateEnabled=true 
      /p:UpdateMode=Foreground 
      /p:ProductName="Tenant Analytics Tool"
      /p:PublishDir=H:\sandbox\deploytesting\SiteA\
      /p:UpdateUrl=\\CATD...[Network Location not network drive]... \sandbox\deploytesting\siteA\
      /p:BootstrapperEnabled=false
      '
      msbuildArchitecture: x64
```

Answer (score 1):

`/t:Publish` will publish to the folder defined in Property  `/p:OutputPath=siteA`. and a subfolder publish will be created. So this example will publish to folder `siteA\publish`

`/p:OutDir` is for `/t:build`. It will include the files from the build result.

For your case i think you can just only use `/p:OutputPath`, not `/p:OutDir`.

As for `$(AssemblyVersion)` not set. It is because AssemblyVersion is not defined in your pipeline **variables**. Syntax `$()` in pipeline will look for variable defined in pipeline `variables` or pipeline predefined variables.